# String Formating Python Exercise Question - LearnPython

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner currently learning Python (the newest version). And I am doing an string formatting exercise on a website called [learnpython](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting). This is the exercise:

**You will need to write a format string which prints out the data using the following syntax: Hello John Doe. Your current balance is $53.44.**

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello"

print(format_string % data)
```

This was my solution:

```
name = "John Doe"
format_string = "Hello"
balance = 53.44
print("%s %s. Your current balance is $%s." % (format_string, name, balance))
```

And when I run the program, I get: Hello John Doe. Your current balance is $53.44.

However, it tells me I'm wrong, that I did not correctly define the variable `format_string` 
I checked the solution and its actually this:

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello %s %s. Your current balance is $%s."

print(format_string % data)
```

But I still don't get it. Is my solution really incorrect although I ran the program and got the same result: Hello John Doe. Your current balance is $53.44.

EDIT:
Some of you are saying my solution doesn't really make sense. Well, I've got a similar solution, hopefully it makes a little more sense:

```
name = "John Doe"
balance = 53.44
print("Hello %s. Your current balance is $%s." % (name, balance))
```

Comment: it's like the way to do a math problem, there's no "right solution", but have "right answer". maybe the question want you to change "only" format_string, but both your solution and the web's answer are way to do the job.

Comment: The `format_string` was meant to contain the, well, format string for the formatting. Your solution is ok except that it doesn't make much sense to include the fixed "Hello" by format parameter `%s` instead of including it directly in the format string.

Comment: In my solution, should I erase  `format_string = "Hello" `and write `print("Hello %s. Your current balance is $%s." % (name, balance)) ` to make it make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your solution is correct. But they are checking the value of format_string because that is what should contain the string format. To be sure you can try changing the variable name and see if you can reproduce the error that way.

Ps- Look at it this way, if you are just printing your statement, you will have to rewrite the complete statement (the c-style formatted string) every time you want it printed. But if you save it in a variable, you can just use that variable whenever you want. They are trying to teach you to write better code and do away with redundant code blocks.

edit: ***The exercise maker also wants you to use tuples to store your values.***
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44) <-- This is a tuple. 
And it decreases variable declarations and a few lines of code.

Comment: Ah, I see. They want me to write better code. I feel dumb for not realizing that. I guess I was too focused on getting the answer "correct." Thank you.

Comment: And teach you how to use tuples too, without declaring too many variables.